# Pre-1980s Sci-fi movie about killer aliens

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, mars

I'm trying to remember an old movie title from when I was a kid. I have not been able to get any information. The movie is pre 1980. Is in another planet (maybe Mars, not sure) and there are this creatures that were thin with more than two arms, all ending in disk. If a person looked at them, the aliens will shine a light that will kill you (you will get your eyes burn or a black circle around the eyes). After you die an egg shaped structure will open and drag you inside.

Comment: Do you mean that they had suckers on the ends of their fingers or that their hands were literally disks?

Comment: I think the hands were disks.

Comment: But now you got me thinking. But I'm pretty sure they were disks.

Comment: It was in colour, I presume?

Comment: I really dont remember because at that time we only had a black and white tv. It could have been. I saw it around the 70's

Comment: Is there anything further you can tell us about the aliens or movie? Were they humanoid other than the arms? The closest I've been able to find so far is the robots from "Earth vs. The Invading Saucers", but they only have two arms.

Comment: Could you be thinking of the movie "Explorers"? It was in 1985, had aliens with four arms (two on their head), whose fingers ended in suction cups, and had several scenes where people were getting lights flashed in their eyes. No burnt eyes or deaths, though.

Comment: I'm trying to remember but I saw this movie about 30 years ago. The plot is in an alien planet. They were not humanoids. As far as I can remember, I think they looked like trees. I think at the end either one of the crew sacrifies himself or gets left behind. The "egg" like structure opened in half and took the dead astronaut inside. I think it was only one and they manage to kill it at the end.

Comment: Was this something that aired on TV, or was it like a Beta/VHS rental? Also, are we talking the US or a different region during the 70s?

Comment: No, it was aired. Although it was in Puerto Rico a long time ago, all of the shows are fron the US. It could be 70's and even a little bit older. I've tried a lot of search combinations on the internet but I can't seem to get a hit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like Mission Mars with Darren McGavin from 1968. It has an alien which has discs for hand. It also has a big white sphere which opens up and takes in the astronaut after killing him.

The IMDB site is here:

[Mission Mars  (1968)](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0063311/)

A YouTube clip can be found here:

[Mission Mars (1968) highlights (Youtube)](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=FP_LWoVzxok)

And here's the alien:

[image]

Comment: @Joe L. Thanks for adding the picture clip of the alien.

Comment: It's so goofy-looking I couldn't resist.

Comment: THAT'S THE ONE. THANK YOU. MY BRAIN ALMOST EXPLODED TRYING TO FIGURE OUT THE MOVIE.