# Identify sci-fi movie about sphere on a moon or planet

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

Probably from 60's or 70's, only remember a scene.  A sphere on the moon or planet, that opened up and you looked into darkness, it tried to or did pull you in and then closed.  Finds a woman in space suit like his under the dirt digs her out and they get into space ship to leave.

Comment: You will need some more details, could you please check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if that helps jog your memory?

Comment: Sounds like "Mission Mars"(1968), except for the woman under the dirt.

Comment: @the guest.  Reading the question that was my exact thought as well until the part about the woman in the spacesuit.  Fortuneteller.  You might check out the following link to see if this rings a bell woman or not.  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89248/pre-1980s-sci-fi-movie-about-killer-aliens/89334#89334