# Crew members of a space ship turned to stone

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I saw an old B&W sci fi movie involving several crew members of a space ship who have been turned to stone\petrified. When another crew member ventures outside to investigate there is a big sphere outside the ship which draws him inside against his will.  I don't remember if the sphere used tentacles or some invisible force.

Comment: Possibly related to the movie identified in the following:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89248/pre-1980s-sci-fi-movie-about-killer-aliens/89334#89334   The part that seems the most matching is the sphere that drags the astronaut inside it.  "This sounds like Mission Mars with Darren McGavin from 1968. It has an alien which has discs for hand. It also has a big white sphere which opens up and takes in the astronaut after killing him."  Check out the clip at timestamp 9:00 minutes in.

Comment: BTW, though you may have seen the movie in B&W originally (as I did) it was actually shot in color.

Comment: That was it.  Thank you!  I first saw this movie when I was around 8 years old.  Freaked me the hell out!

Comment: Glad to hear this was it.  I have added this as the formal answer below for tracking in case someone else might have the same question later.

Answer (score 0):

Answer the same as noted in the post: [Mission Mars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89248/pre-1980s-sci-fi-movie-about-killer-aliens/89334#89334). The part that triggered the match recognition is the sphere that drags the astronaut inside it.

*"It also has a big white sphere which opens up and takes in the astronaut after killing him."*

Check out the clip at timestamp 9:00 minutes in:  [Youtube clip](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=FP_LWoVzxok)